# regression model for toxic elements and epigenetic age

Tags: r, statistics, regression

We are trying to find the association between soil toxic elements and epigenetic age acceleration in four different cities: BKI, DAUS, SRINA, and PALLA. We have measured the soil toxic elements using ICP-MS, and epigenetic age acceleration was calculated after regressing with chronological age. We are using a total of 10 toxic elements.

However, I am facing two problems:
1.The number of participants varies for all four cities: BKI (1000 participants), DAUS (250 participants), SRINA (200 participants), PALLA (100 participants). How should I account for these varying numbers of individuals?

2.We would like to measure the association of all 10 toxic elements with epigenetic age in each city.

Currently, I am using the model below, but it provides associations between all elements and epigenetic age acceleration. We want output separated based on the city as well.

```r
library("QuantPsyc")
data <- read.table("clr.clean.file2.txt", header=T, sep=",")

model1 <- lm (epigenetic_age_acceleration ~ 
   As + Se + Fe + Co + Zn + Mn + Hg + Sb + Mo + Pb + 
   Smoking_Status + Sex + Age, data = data)
model1
model1.stat<-lm.beta (model1)

model1.stat

As
0.0256056478741109
Se
0.00499178037586947
Fe
0.00210283404005497
Co
-0.00916637143431217
Zn
0.0639371964557919
Mn
-0.0213600659139311
Hg
0.0328431516176923
Sb
0.000169338014091565
Mo
-0.0200956999960768
```

```
suggested code work of me;
```

```r
IEAA_elements <- lm (epigentic_age_acceleration ~ 0 + city + 
  city:(As +Se + Fe + Co + Zn +Mn + Hg + Sb+ Mo +Pb +   
        Smoking_Status + Sex + Age), data = data)
```

```
cf <- confint(IEAA_elements)
cf
```

Now not sure how to merge confidence interval with regression outputs?

```
Also not sure if I have to use GLM model then should I use gaussian family but not sure about link type? and what role does it has in GLM model
# Fit a GLM
  formula <- as.formula(epigentic_age_acceleration ~ 0 + city + 
  city:(As +Se + Fe + Co + Zn +Mn + Hg + Sb+ Mo +Pb +   
        Smoking_Status + Sex + Age))
  model <- glm(formula, data = data, family = gaussian(link="identity"))
```

Comment: Should go to https://stats.stackexchange.com and you should post the result of `summary` on that “lm”-object as an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `city` is a categorical (factor) variable in your data set, you probably want:

```r
epigenetic_age_acceleration ~ 
   0 + city + city:(As + Se + Fe + Co + Zn + Mn + Hg + Sb + Mo + Pb + 
   Smoking_Status + Sex + Age)
```

`0+city` says to fit a separate intercept for every city (and suppress the overall intercept). `city:(<stuff>)` says to fit the *interaction* between `city` and `<stuff>`.

You don't typically need to account explicitly for different intensities of samples in different cities: this will get handled by the regression framework.

Comment: it shows error, could you please suggest how to avoid it, i have updated above code and error?

Comment: You forgot a close-parenthesis at the end of the formula ...

Comment: Thanks, it is sorted now, I will update the code. would it be possible to calculate upper and lower confidence interval

Comment: `confint()` ....

Comment: If this answer solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.

Comment: thanks Ben for your all help, but now not sure how to merge confidence interval with regression outputs?

Comment: And also if I want to run GLM model then please suggest if the above mention code is correct or not?

Comment: Dear Ben, some people says that this is not the correct way to include city as interaction term? could you please advised how we can improve this code and also I just want to run association with single toxic element as some of these might show collinearity?